# Unix find -mtime {a negative or postive value}

Tags: unix, gnu-findutils

What do `find -mtime -4` and `find -mtime +4` do? I cannot understand the examples given in the man page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per man page:

```
-mtime n
    File’s  data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
    for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
    of file modification times.
```

The argument to `-mtime` is interpreted as the number of whole days in the age of the file. `-mtime +n` means strictly greater than, `-mtime -n` means strictly less than.

So in your case,

`-4` meaning less than 4 days.
`+4` meaning more than 4 days i.e. 4*24 hours.

Comment: Thanks! I got my answer!

Answer (score 11):

Well, I can.

> ```
> -mtime n
> ```
>
> File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. See the comments for `-atime` to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times

```
find . -mtime 0   # find files modified between now and 1 day ago
                  # (i.e., within the past 24 hours)
find . -mtime -1  # find files modified less than 1 day ago
                  # (i.e., within the past 24 hours, as before)
find . -mtime 1   # find files modified between 24 and 48 hours ago
find . -mtime +1  # find files modified more than 48 hours ago
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I know this thing. I wanted to know if I give any negative value then what does it mean?

Comment: Nope! I used-- find . -mtime -4 & find . -mtime +4 .They are giving different results.

Comment: you are absolutley right, sorry and thx for correcting me, after such a long time.

Answer (score 0):

None of my searches - be they for "negative", "mtime", "strictly" - found the normative text in the man page, but it's there, oy, a quarter of the way through:

```
   Numeric arguments can be specified as

   +n     for greater than n,

   -n     for less than n,

   n      for exactly n.
```

But who needs the man page when Google's top match is Stack Overflow, where @SMA and @wgitscht had already given the correct answer?  Well, it's nice to know it's de jure and not a happy accident.