# What is this command is exactly doing?

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, command

I'm trying to reproduce a log gzip cron in other servers,

The "template" I have is:

```
00 02 * * * cd ~/project_folder/application/logs; find . -type f -name "*.php" -mtime +4 -exec gzip {} \;
```

Does this gzip the .php's in that dir every day and deletes the uncompressed files?

Comment: I'd appreciate comment with downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does compress them daily, and gzip automatically deletes source files afterwards. The `00 02 * * *` at line beginning means 02:00 every day.

From `man gzip`:

> -k, --keep        Keep (do not delete) input files during compression or decompression.

That means, without `-k`, `gzip` implies `rm`.

Comment: But I don't understand why the old ones are not in the server

Comment: @toni-michel-caubet Edited my answer. I was stupid not recalling that gzip removes source files by default.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Also, do you know the part '-mtime +4' ? I see in the server that there are still 4-5 uncompressed files. Does it check that they are +4 days old? Thanks!

Comment: @toni-michel-caubet You're right, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700943/unix-find-mtime-a-negative-or-postive-value . Actually a little Googling will give you that answer

Answer (score 2):

You can visit https://crontab-generator.org/ it's a good tool for generating crontab lines and you will understand what the numbers and asterisks mean. Now if you choose

- 0 for minutes
- 2am for hour
- leave everything else as it is
- for the command use `cd ~/project_folder/application/logs; find . -type f -name "*.php" -mtime +4 -exec gzip {} \;`

and click the **generate crontab line** you will see an example of the times it will run. Plus it will add this chuck `>/dev/null 2>&1` don't worry about it, it's an output instruction for the command and good to have it in the crontab.

[image]

> The argument to -mtime is interpreted as the number of whole days in the age of the file. -mtime +n means strictly greater than, -mtime -n means strictly less than.

So this command will find and gzip all the `*.php` files where the latest modification time (`mtime`) of those files are greater than 4 days.

Edit: 
I couldn't recall the `-k` argument of `gzip` too. So as per [@chang-qian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3946355/chang-qian) response.

> Without `-k`, `gzip` implies that it will delete the original files after their compression.